# Explain log likelihood behaviour

Tags: maximum-likelihood, model-selection, likelihood

(This question is related to a previous one I made, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118085/goodness-of-fit-observed-vs-simulated-data))

I have a set of 2D observations (measured data) of sample size $N$:

$$O = \{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ..., (x_N, y_N)\}$$

I also have a model $S(v_1, v_2, ..., v_p)$, which depends on $p$ parameters, and attempts to reproduce the observed data by generating *artificial* "observed" data.

The *number of elements* and spatial distribution of the artificial data generated with the model, depend on the values given to the $p$ parameters each time the model is used.

For example, here is some observed/measured data (left) of sample size $N=1000$, and some artificial data (right) of sample size $M=350$, obtained by fixing the $p$ parameters in $S$ to some values:

[image]

By varying the parameters of the model $S$, I generate $k$ sets of artificial data (each one uniquely described by the values assigned to the $p$ parameters) that I call $A_1, A_2, ..., A_k$, where:

$$A_r = \{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ..., (x_{M_r}, y_{M_r})\}$$

(where the sets $A_1, A_2, ..., A_k$ have sample sizes $M_1, M_2, ..., M_k$)

I need to select from $A_1, A_2, ..., A_k$ the set that presents the *best fit* with my observed data $O$.

To do this I apply a log-likelihood test to each artificial data set:

$$L_r = -\sum_{i=1}^N \log ( \frac{1}{M_r} \sum_{j=1}^{M_r} e^{-\frac{(x_i - x_j)^2}{2}}  e^{-\frac{(y_i - y_j)^2}{2}} )\;;\; r=1,..,k$$

where $(x_i, y_i)$ and $(x_j, y_j)$ represent observed and artificial data respectively.

As I understand it, I need to find the artificial set that minimizes the log-likelihood, and this will be the one that shows the best fit.

Something unusual (to me) happens with the likelihood values as the sizes of the artificial sets increase:

[image]

where each blue dot represents the log-likelihood value $L_r$ (y axis) obtained for an artificial set $A_r$ with sample size $M_r$ (x axis). The red line is the sample size for the observed data ($N=1000$).

Why is the log-likelihood small for artificial sets with few elements, climbs to a maximum and then starts dropping as the sample size of the artificial sets increase?

I would have expected the exact *opposite* behaviour, given that I am after the *minimum* log-likelihood value.

(The python code I used to generate these tests can be downloaded from [here](http://pastebin.com/yc7wVC80))

Answer (score 1):

Several things could be wrong; I can only suggest some things to look at.

What's the smallest $N$ to debug with — 5, 10 ?
Plot that with $N_r = N/2, N, 2N$ .
Follow the steps, with rug plots or quantiles of
$|p_i - q_j|, exp_{ij}$, row sums.
(It's not clear to me if $1 / M_r$ scaling is correct, maybe row sums 1
in the $N \times N_r$ array of $exp_{ij}$ ?)

$exp^{ - |p - q|^2 / r }$ is very sensitive to radius $r$.
And it doesn't scale:
as $N_r \to \infty$, the $exp$ s crowd near 1 (I believe).
There are lots of other metrics between 2d point sets;
average nearest-neighbor with nnear say 10 is fast and easy with 
[scipy.spatial.cKDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) .

Can the data be viewed as a continuous terrain, 1 at the data points, falling off to 0 in between ?
If so, the average error of the $N_r$ points interpolated at the $N$ sounds
like a reasonable metric; see (ahem)
[inverse-distance-weighted-idw-interpolation-with-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104781/inverse-distance-weighted-idw-interpolation-with-python/3119544#3119544).
And terrains are nice to plot.